# Different segues from a reusable table cell

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I'm new to programming and have come across my first head wrecking problem on xcode/swift.

I have made a table view with a reusable cell. I'm going to have 4 different cells and I want these to each perform different segues to another view controller.

However, at the moment I only seem to be able to choose one segue for all the cells that are returned.

I tried implementing an if statement based on the indexPath.row number in my 'numbersTableViewCellDidTouch' function, but keep getting an error message saying 'use of unresolved identifier IndexPath'. I'm guessing because it is a delegate function I can't use indexPath in this function, because indexPath belongs to the Navigation View Controller rather than the cell.

I'm scratching my head as to how to perform different segues based on the position of the returned cell....can anyone help?

FYI I have copied my code below for my table view controller.

```
import UIKit

class NumbersTableViewController: UITableViewController, NumbersTableViewCellDelegate {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().setStatusBarStyle(UIStatusBarStyle.LightContent, animated: true)
    tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 85
    tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}

@IBAction func menuButtonDidTouch(sender: AnyObject) {
    performSegueWithIdentifier("MenuSegue", sender: self)
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 4
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("StoryCell") as NumbersTableViewCell

    cell.titleLabel.text = numbersData[indexPath.row]["title"] as? String
    cell.summaryLabel.text = numbersData[indexPath.row]["subtitle"] as? String
    cell.articleImageView.image = UIImage(named: "cat-pic2")
    cell.delegate = self

    return cell
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)
    performSegueWithIdentifier("NumbersArticleSegue", sender: self)
}

//Mark: NumbersTableViewCellDelegate

func numbersTableViewCellDidTouch(cell: NumbersTableViewCell, sender: AnyObject) {
 performSegueWithIdentifier("NumbersArticleSegue", sender: self)        
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your "numbersTableViewCellDidTouch" function, the arguments are the cell and its sender. There is no reference to an indexPath which is why you get that error.

But there is a way around this. Using [UITableView's](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/indexPathForCell:) indexPathForCell: function which will give you the NSIndexPath you are looking for.

So you could change your function to be:

```
func numbersTableViewCellDidTouch(cell: NumbersTableViewCell, sender: AnyObject) {

 //indexPathForCell(_:UITableViewCell) returns a NSIndexPath?
 //if let will safely unwrap for us.
 if let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForCell(cell) 
 {
   //Run if statements to check indexPath.row
   performSegueWithIdentifier("NumbersArticleSegue", sender: self)
 }

 //Should still have a default action if indexPathForCell(_:UITableViewCell) returns a nil value 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you don't want to use dynamic cells, but static ones instead.
You can define static cells via storyboard..